# Geometrically connected components of an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Suppose that $G$ is an algebraic group over a field $k$. Let $G^o$be the connected component of the identity. Since $G^0$ contains a $k$-rational point (the identity) therefore it is geometrically connected. I am wondering whether the remaining connected components of $G$ are also geometrically connected.

Comment: A good exercise: for any $k$-group scheme $G$ locally of finite type, the connected components of $G$ that are geometrically connected over $k$ are in bijective correspondence with the $k$-points of the etale quotient $G/G^0$. In particular, they're all geometrically connected if and only if $G/G^0$ is a constant $k$-scheme. (hint: the real content is descending from $k_s$ down to $k$)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, take for example $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $G=\mu_p$ for some prime $p>2$. Then $G$ has only two connected components, whereas $G_\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ has $p$.